# Can someone inject malicious code into this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm considering the use of a, 'What's on your mind?' comment box in one of my pages.

```
     var statusBox = function() 
     {
     $(".btn").click(function() {

     var post = $(".whatsUp").val();
     $('<li>').text(post).prependTo(".entry");
     $('.whatsUp').val('');
     $('.charRemainder').text('130');
   });
   $('.whatsUp').keyup(function() {
     var postLength = $(this).val().length;
     var charactersRemaining = 130 - postLength;
     $('.charRemainder').text(charactersRemaining);
  });
 };
 $(document).ready(statusBox);
```

Question:
Could someone inject malicious code by way of this utility?
No database involved.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the existing answer, there is no injection possible that could cause any harm to a back-end server, as this is purely a front-end functionality.

That being said, client-side JavaScript is inherently unsafe in the sense that a user can edit a web page's JavaScript code through their browser. Nothing can really be done about that when it comes to front-end functionality.

However, when passing data to a server, it is extremely important to remember to not do your error trapping and input validation in JavaScript alone, since a user can easily remove this logic. All such validation should be done on the back-end.

Comment: Good to know Michael! I am trying to avoid the additional time and everything else that involving a database would add to this. I'm not very experienced in this area. However creating and including one is not off the table and in fact I WOULD have done this purely with javascript!

Answer (score 2):

No. If this is not saved on the server in any form then you are not vulnerable to SQL injection or XSS (cross site scripting).

I can't imagine the use of a comment box that doesn't save somewhere, though.

Comment: Thank you Comptonburger. Yes, you raise another question; I have been playing with ideas regarding 'saving'. And so far the one that seems reasonable enough is some additional code with something like a timer that checks for entries. If one is found then it's copied to another page etc. Better yet, no timer just copy once the button event occurs. This without any communication to the server, I don't know.

Comment: @Geeklin It is impossible for an user to be able to see content from another user without some kind of server. Any Javascript DOM manipulation you do client-side will only be visible (like the name suggests) to that specific client ... Unless you persist those actions somewhere

Comment: localStorage or cookies could be used to save the comments and render them again for the same client. However Matias is right that without a server there is no way to share these comments with other clients.

Comment: I will add that if you did choose to save these on a server and show them to other clients, your code is safe from XSS, because the jQuery `.text` function escapes any HTML. This prevents clients from typing JavaScript into the comment box that could be used to, say, steal private cookies from other clients.